# get user based on id using json

Tags: json, node.js

I want to get a user from a json file based on the id, what I have below only works if the ids are in order

```
 router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
// First read existing users.
fs.readFile( __dirname + "/" + "users.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    people = JSON.parse( data );

    var user =  people.users[req.params.id]
    if (err) {
        res.status = 500;
        res.send(err).end();
        return;
    }
    console.log( user );
    res.end( JSON.stringify(user));
});
})
```

the json:

```
{"users[{"firstname":"stoffel","lastname":"clement","id":9},{"firstname":"stoffel","lastname":"clement","id":1},{"firstname":"liam","lastname":"murphy","id":"2"},{"firstname":"stoffel","lastname":"murphy","id":"3"}]}
```

Comment: You'll have to filter the array to search for the entry with the correct id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is accessing the `users` array by *index*. You want to search for it by `id`. (And when your `users` array is sorted according to `id`,the position in the array will match the `id` (assuming you are using zero-indexing) which is why it works).

If you're using a library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) you can do something like...

`var user = _.find(users, ['id', req.params.id])`

Answer (score -1):

Your JSON looks funky to me.  I think you need a closing quote and colon after the users part, i.e.

```
{"users": [{"firstname":"stoffel","lastname":"clement","id":9},{"firstname":"stoffel","lastname":"clement","id":1},{"firstname":"liam","lastname":"murphy","id":"2"},{"firstname":"stoffel","lastname":"murphy","id":"3"}]};
```

Comment: If this were the problem, it wouldn't work at all. *"what I have below only works if the ids are in order"*

Comment: additionally, if it were in fact the problem, answering the question isn't the right way to solve it... leave a comment asking for clarification and vote/flag to close as typo.